# Programmatically configure widget face

Tags: android, configuration, interface, widget

How to programmatically configure widget face? I have create widget:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:background="@drawable/widget"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_title"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/edit_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/edit"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_edit" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Shape (@drawable/widget):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

I need set background color, background transpanency, border color and font size/color for TextViews in the configuration activity. But how to get TextView object and how to access shape properities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike a normal activity, in a widget you cannot directly instantiate a `TextView` with `findViewById`.

You will need to instantiate a `RemoteViews` object, passing your package name as a parameter:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
```

And then affect the `TextView` using the method `setInt` of the `remoteViews` object with the original function of the `TextView` as a parameter:

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_title, "setBackgroundResource", android.R.color.white);
```

Finally, update the Widget:

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

You can try other combinations using the method 
`public void setInt (int viewId, String methodName, int value)` and passing the original `methodName` as parameter, but for some reason not everything is allowed in the Widget context. Try it out!